# How to call localhost API from inside a Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, docker-container

I have a localhost API - `localhost:39214`. I have to access this API from inside a Docker container and the container is running Node.js API inside it.

I am getting the below error when the Docker container application is trying to access that URL:

> Connection to Message Api Failed connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:39214

and I am using docker-compose.yml file.

How can I access the external host API from inside the Docker container? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

#### Linux

The simplest way to do it on Linux is to run your Docker container on the host network. In the `docker-compose.yml` file add this key to your *service*:

```
network_mode: "host"
```

This will make the host's network available to the container.

Reference -  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#network_mode.

#### MacOS

Docker on Mac doesn't support network mode host. Instead, you can use `host.docker.internal` as `localhost` inside the container, so `host.docker.internal:39214` in your case.

Keep in mind that this method is for development purposes and does not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop.

Reference - https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds-for-all-platforms.

Comment: I am using windows platform version 10. is there any way to connect that localhost API from docker container. I am ok to modify docker compose file.

Comment: I went through above use cases you mentioned. but don't have knowledge about to configure - `host.docker.internal` in docker compose file. any references if you have would be helpful.

Comment: @SSD `host.docker.internal` doesn't work for Windows, only Mac. You can try installing Linux on Windows with WSL2. It's my best suggestion, I'm not very familiar with Windows, unfortunately.